# How to update a field in MongoDB from another field value?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to update a field name `Date` in `collection-B` from `collection-A` by comparing the `articleid` of both fields. if `articelid` id matches then the `date` will be inserted in the matching document of `collection-B`
**How will I update the date field**?

**Collection-A**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("6368cef0cb0c042cbc5cc4e8"),
"articleid" : "159448182", 
 "type" : "online",
 "Date":"2023-01-01"
}
```

**Collection-B**

```
     {
    "_id" : ObjectId("34342dd123b0c042cbc5cc4e8"),
    "articleid" : "159448182", 
     "guide" : "yes",
     "Date":"2023-04-01"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think For updating documents in collection-B you have to first fetch the collection-A documents and then update it , cross collection update is not there in mongoDb currently.

```
const collectionAResponse = await Collection-A.findOne({articleid: "159448182"}, {Date: 1});

if(collectionAResponse){
      const collectionBResponse = await Collection-B.updateMany({articleid: "159448182"},{$set:{Date: collectionAResponse.Date}})
}
```